# Determine cycles of n length in a relational database table

Tags: java, mysql, cycle, wikipedia

Given a table that relates things to each, for example,

```
Subject   Object
----------------
Blue      Red
Red       Blue
Red       Green
Green     Yellow
Yellow    Blue
```

how would one go about looking for cycles, for example,

```
Blue -> Red -> Blue

Maybe even:
Blue -> Red -> Green -> Yellow -> Blue
```

The table is stored in a MySQL database. I was thinking of using Java to select a pair and then look for the inverse using a loop, at least for short cycles. 
Or would it make sense to use a graph database for this kind of problem? Any pointers would be helpful!

Wikipedia did this for its category system, but I don't what how their category data is stored. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Dump_reports/Category_cycles

Comment: What about RED subject - it has two pairs?

Comment: Subjects can be linked to multiple objects.